# Wordpress: Get data and sort

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

**Table Name: wp_ninja_forms_subs**

```
Data in table

id  (int)     = 1 
user_id (int)  = 1
form_id (int)  = 1
data (longtext)    = `a:12:{i:0;a:2:{s:8:"field_id";i:16;s:10:"user_value";s:4:"test";}i:1;a:2:{s:8:"field_id";i:6;s:10:"user_value";s:4:"test";}i:2;a:2:{s:8:"field_id";i:15;s:10:"user_value";s:14:"(808) 080-8080";}i:3;a:2:{s:8:"field_id";i:8;s:10:"user_value";s:14:"asdf@gmail.com";}i:4;a:2:{s:8:"field_id";i:10;s:10:"user_value";s:6:"sfasdf";}i:5;a:2:{s:8:"field_id";i:3;s:10:"user_value";s:12:"ksfasdlkfadf";}i:6;a:2:{s:8:"field_id";i:11;s:10:"user_value";s:0:"";}i:7;a:2:{s:8:"field_id";i:12;s:10:"user_value";s:5:"Admin";}i:8;a:2:{s:8:"field_id";i:13;s:10:"user_value";s:8:"Forgtown";}i:9;a:2:{s:8:"field_id";i:14;s:10:"user_value";s:8:"sadfasdf";}i:10;a:2:{s:8:"field_id";i:4;s:10:"user_value";s:1:"7";}i:11;a:2:{s:8:"field_id";i:5;s:10:"user_value";s:0:"";}}`

date_updated = 2014-01-25 11:02:01
```

---

**Query**

```
$subs_results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_ninja_forms_subs WHERE form_id = 1 ORDER BY date_updated DESC")
```

How to print "data" field value?

Also I want data sort by "data(phone)". is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will convert this string into array and print "data" field value...

```
foreach ($subs_results as $sub)
{
    $data = unserialize($sub->data);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default `$wpdb->get_results()` returns an array of objects, so you probably want this:

```
foreach ($subs_results as $sub)  {
    echo $sub->data;
}
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results

Note that it will print this field's value for **each** record in `wp_ninja_forms_subs` table.